А вы читаете идеографические словари?
Мне встретился такой словарь:
Леонтьева Т. В. Идеографический словарь русской социальной лексики : общество и человек /
Т. В. Леонтьева. — Екатеринбург : Ажур, 2018. — 554 с
Очень интересное издание!
Например, всем известны слова с собирательным значением: ворьё, жульё. А в этом словаре есть: лЮдье, людь, людцы, людка  т.д.  Также приведены примеры и указаны источники.
Ну и людцы пошли! Людье кажут, что я дрянь молода. Ой, какая людь здесь! Народность как хлынула мост переходить! А наша людка, ты видишь какая: все говорит — никто не ворушится.
В результате получается красочная  картина социального общества в определенный период времени. Но много ли у нас идеографических словарей такого типа и какими из них вы пользуетесь? Что интересного в них можно найти.

Очень интересный словарь. Скачал себе.

Мне тоже нравится, но много ли таких словарей? Хотелось бы, чтобы  были раскрыты и другие темы.

Мне особо не встречались такие словари. Даже на Грамоте.ру нет. Я лично никогда не пользовался такими словарями. Но этот словарь хочу изучить. Думаю, узнаю много чего нового.
